# Как достать из массива cookie элемент

Tags: php

В том случае, если мы задаем элементы массива при помощи цикла for, где каждый элемент записываем как `setcookie("visit$i",  $allSite[$i][1]);`, после проверки такой записи при помощи вывода всего массива через `var_dump` все работает успешно - куки заданы корректно, а вот вывести элемент при помощи `echo`, как и использовать его в любом другом месте при помощи записи кода `echo $_COOKIE['visit$i'];` в идентичном цикле не выходит. Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: попробуй двойные кавычки ставить 'visit$i' . если ты в цикле их выводишь то нужен $i, а так обычную цифру ставь

Comment: Проверь, есть ли cookie в браузере и выложи весь код с циклом.

Comment: кавычки на двойные смените